# Failed Jobs not being executed by Quartz in a clustered environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have built a project using Spring Quartz with a clustered environment. I am trying to test if the jobs can be picked up , in case the server that initiated them shut down. While it works perfectly as expected for Cron Triggers, same cannot be said about the SimpleTrigger job.

For Cron Triggers which have not been executed yet, Quartz runs the job without any hassle.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Start the servers at port 8080 and port 8081.
2. Schedule a job using server at port 8081.
3. Shut down the server while the job is running.

This is what I get when the ClusterManager picks up the jobs:

```
2022-06-22 13:37:52.659  INFO 23852 --- [_ClusterManager] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: detected 2 failed or restarted instances.
2022-06-22 13:37:52.661  INFO 23852 --- [_ClusterManager] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "MacBook-Pro.local1655885157031"'s failed in-progress jobs.
2022-06-22 13:37:52.677  INFO 23852 --- [_ClusterManager] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "MacBook-Pro.local1655885169333"'s failed in-progress jobs.
2022-06-22 13:37:52.720  INFO 23852 --- [_ClusterManager] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: ......Deleted 1 complete triggers(s).
2022-06-22 13:37:52.722  INFO 23852 --- [_ClusterManager] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : ClusterManager: ......Cleaned-up 1 other failed job(s).
```

This is how my Job  looks like:

```
public class ApiJob implements Job {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiJob.class);
    
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        this.context=context;
        log.info("Job Execution Started");
        JobDataMap map=context.getMergedJobDataMap();
        ApiRequest request=new ApiRequest(map.getString("message"));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2*60*1000);
            log.info("Job scheduled...{}",context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
Trigger trigger=TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), "quartz-jobs-triggers")
                .withDescription("Random trigger")
                .startAt(Date.from(startTime.toInstant()))
                //Add custom logic here?
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
            .build();
```

And finally how I setup the clustering in the `application.properties`:

```
#Quartz Properties
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```